# How to stop content starch to under title bar in making a NSWindow?

Tags: swift, cocoa

If I use this code the content would be in correct position in window like this:

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.wantsLayer = true
        self.view.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.blue.cgColor
        self.view.layer?.cornerRadius = 100

    }

}
```

[image]

But if I use this code the content would go below the title and that is not I want:

```
import Cocoa

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    
    private lazy var window: NSWindow = NSWindow()
    
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        
        window.styleMask = [.titled, .closable, .miniaturizable, .resizable, .fullSizeContentView]
        window.backingType = .buffered
        window.title = "Window"
        
        let blueView: NSView = NSView()
        blueView.wantsLayer = true
        blueView.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.blue.cgColor
        blueView.layer?.cornerRadius = 100

        window.contentView = blueView

        window.center()
        window.setFrameAutosaveName("Main Window")
        window.isMovableByWindowBackground = true
        window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(window)
        
    }

}
```

[image]

I know that I can fix this issue with constraints, but this should not be an issue to fix it because it is the content and it should be all in visible part of window not under the titlebar. How can I fix this issue without having to use constraints and trying find a hard coded value for fixing the issue, using constraints with a hard coded value to bringing the content to visible part is not the best looking approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are using `.fullSizeContentView` as one of the window's `styleMask`. When combined with `.titled`, `.fullSizeContentView` means that the content view will extend "below" the title bar.

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/stylemask/1644646-fullsizecontentview):

> When set, the window’s `contentView` consumes the full size of the window. Although you can combine this constant with other window style masks, it is respected only for windows with a title bar. Note that using this mask opts in to layer-backing. Use the `contentLayoutRect` or the `contentLayoutGuide` to lay out views underneath the title bar–toolbar area.

So a simple fix is to just remove `.fullSizeContentView`.

If you do want this style mask for some reason, you can add `blueView` as a subview of the content view and constrain it to `contentLayoutGuide`.

```
blueView.wantsLayer = true
blueView.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.blue.cgColor
blueView.layer?.cornerRadius = 100
blueView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
let contentView = NSView()
window.contentView = contentView
contentView.addSubview(blueView)

// contentLayoutGuide can apparently also be an NSView
// for more info, see: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/69189
if let layoutGuide = window.contentLayoutGuide as? NSLayoutGuide {
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        blueView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.leftAnchor),
        blueView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.rightAnchor),
        blueView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.topAnchor),
        blueView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
    ])
}
```